# Using environment variable in create-react-app package.json proxy

Tags: reactjs, json, environment-variables, create-react-app, package.json

I would like to set the "proxy"-property in the package.json file of a create-react-app project to the value of an environment variable called "REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL". The variable is stored in the .env.development.local file. I can't find the right way to do this. What is the right notation to access the variable? Each way I tried ended in the following error, when starting the app with `npm start`:

```
When "proxy" is specified in package.json it must start with either http:// or https://
```

This error probably occurred because the value isn't accessed correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify in your .env.development.local:

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=[your url]
```

you can use `source .env.development.local` to store the value and then use it using $REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL.

For example in your package.json you could do this:

```
"scripts": {
   "deploy": "react-scripts build; source .env; ./scripts/deploy.sh $REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL"
}
```